# How to have Kitchen CI run a script on success?

Tags: chef, inspec

I've got a Chef repo that uses test-kitchen. I have a pretty good battery of tests, and when I run the tests and they're successful, I have a `vendor.sh` script that does some cleanup and a Berks vendor. What I'd like to be able to do is automatically run that script. I suppose I could just put `kitchen test {box}` into that script, but then I'd have to find a way to detect success (maybe this is easy) and deal with output and things like that; I'd rather just have Kitchen do it.

I googled and searched and found nothing. Does anyone know a way?

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It's a perfectly legitimate question: How do you execute a script at the end of a Kitchen CI run? Every non-CM CI tool in the world supports this.

Comment: FTR `kitchen test` does exit with non 0 status if there was a failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is lifecycle hooks.

https://kitchen.ci/docs/reference/lifecycle-hooks/

For example, you could have this in you kitchen.yml file.

```
suites:
- name: default
  lifecycle:
    post_verify:
    - local: <script>
```

Comment: Sorry so late in accepting answer, I suppose I lost track of this. :)